# How can i make same button in multiple view controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there anyway to add same scroll menubar at the navigation bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801429/is-there-anyway-to-add-same-scroll-menubar-at-the-navigation-bar)

May be it is a stupid question but i have to solve it at any cost because my whole project depending on it.My question is,

I have four view controller A, B, C, D.

**A has 4 buttons btn1,btn2,btn3,brn4**. when i will start click on btn then

btn1 click -> A controller reload or current controller reload;

btn2 click -> B controller open;

btn3 click -> C controller open;

btn4 click -> D controller open;

**B has 4 buttons btn1,btn2,btn3,brn4**. when i will start click on btn then

btn1 click -> A controller open;

btn2 click -> B controller reload or current controller reload;

btn3 click -> C controller open;

btn4 click -> D controller open;

**C has 4 buttons btn1,btn2,btn3,brn4**. when i will start click on btn then

btn1 click -> A controller open;

btn2 click -> B controller open;

btn3 click -> C controller reload or current controller reload;

btn4 click -> D controller open;

**D has 4 buttons btn1,btn2,btn3,brn4**. when i will start click on btn then

btn1 click -> A controller open;

btn2 click -> B controller open;

btn3 click -> C controller open;

btn4 click -> D controller reload or current controller reload;

I need detail process how can i do that?

Thanks In Advance.

**EDIT:**

All of my these controller (A,B,C,D) are in tabbar controller and buttons are in a scrollview which are at the top of the controller.I have attaching a image of these UI,till now i have done this....

[image]

further any query please do not hesitate to ask.
Thanks again

**EDIT 2:**

This is scrollview of button which i have imported in every controller `viewDidload` of `tabbar` items.

```
scrollButtonView = [[scrollViewButtons alloc] initWithNibName:@"scrollViewButtons" bundle:nil];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 43);
scrollButtonView.view.frame = frame;
scrollButtonView.view.userInteractionEnabled =YES;
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:scrollButtonView.view];
```

here is the code where i want to switch the controller on button click.but problem is when i import those A,B,C,D then i found an error `Unknown controller`

```
 -(void)mybuttons:(id)sender{   
NSLog(@"mybuttons called");
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
if (button.tag == 0) {
    NSLog(@"hey have clicked first button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected]; //sets the background Image]
}
else {
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

}
if (button.tag == 1) {
    NSLog(@"hey have clicked second button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
else  if (button.tag == 2) {
    NSLog(@"hey have clicked first button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
    [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]

  //UIViewController *newController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerViewController" bundle:nil];
    //UINavigationController *myCustomerController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newController] autorelease];
    //UINavigationController *myCustomerController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *secondViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomerViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 2;
}
 else if (button.tag == 3) {
    NSLog(@"hey have clicked second button, this is my tag : %i \n\n",button.tag);
      [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_topmenu_hover.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; //sets the background Image]
      //[self.navigationController pushViewController:cstViewController animated:YES];
       self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 3;
     }
   }
```

**EDIT3:**

Any way i have to solve the problem so i have tried a lot of way but i missed a simple matter. when i want to change the tap bar then then also i am getting these buttons so i have solved this problem a little bit different way..see my answer you will get the answer..

further any question pls ask. Any how i have to solve the problem.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have written so far?

Comment: Sometime ago i have this need especially because the tabbar in landscape mode(in ipad) doesn't come in the full length at the bottom. Else if you are not making an ipad application then UITabBarController is your answer.

Comment: I can't Understand Your Question.What u mean by Controller Open,U want to load Four Action Simultaneously. Then Add four Target with Different Selector for that Button. So u can control different view controller Using single Button.

Comment: I have edited my question can you give any more suggestion?

Comment: @AnilKothari may be now you should see my post after editing.

Comment: @AshleyMills will i post my code now,because i have edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - that implements the functionality you are describing.

The buttons in the scroll view just replicates the tab bar functionality - resulting in a confusing user experience.

Comment: Basically all of my controllers (A,B,C,D) are tabbar controller and button are in a scrollview at the navigation bar of these controllers.

Comment: Why not just remove the buttons? They're just replicating the tab bar functionality - resulting in a confusing user experience.

Comment: you have given me a nice solution but i do not know how can i do that. will you please please explain it step by step. if still now you are facing problem to understand my problem then i have posted my question with explanation in another post..here is the link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8801429/is-there-anyway-to-add-same-scroll-menubar-at-the-navigation-bar

Comment: suppose buttons of the scroll are directing in different controllers not tabbar item's view controller then how i will do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing yourself with such complicated functionality although I would like to suggest you use storyboard (New ios 5 feature) it will definitely help you for your problem with less coding.

You have to connect the outlet to from on view controller to other three view and again from other three view to this view. You can find more details here.[Link](http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html)

Comment: I have edited my question can you give me any more suggestion without your current suggestion?

Comment: I have edited my code again now plz give me soliution. NOTE THAT: pls also see my comment of my code.

Comment: I love Storyboard, but when you use it, you are limiting your deployment pool to only devices running iOS 5.0 or better

Comment: @ElJay but i have to solve it in my way and i have not any idea about storyboard and i have not enough time to do this process using storyboard.so can do solve my problem now without storyboard?